# Azure DevOps api : PowerShell: Create Branch AND link an existing WorkItem to it: get a red '(!) Branch link could not be read' on the Task's page

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

In AzDO I have a (brand new) Task (#24468), not associated with any Branch.

First, set my token:

```
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($AzToken)"))
```

This excerpt works perfectly fine, it creates the branch in AzDO:

```
$targetBranchName = "ci"
$targetBranchId = (az repos ref list -p "myProjectName" -r "myRepoName" --filter heads/$($targetBranchName) | ConvertFrom-Json).ObjectId
$branchFullName ="feature/0024468-New_program_to_do_something"
$branchJSON = az repos ref create --name refs/heads/$($branchFullName) --object-id $targetBranchId --organization "https://dev.azure.com/myOrgName" --project myProjectName --repository myRepoName
```

... I look on the web site, in AzDO and I now see the branch - it has no errors.

This works fine, it gets the Task:

```
$taskNo = "24468"
$urlWI = -join("https://dev.azure.com/myOrgName/myProjectName/_apis/wit/workitems/",$taskNo,"?api-version=5.1")
$wiJSON = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $urlWI -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get 
$wiJSON._links # shows the links
$wiJSON.fields # shows the fields

$taskURL = $wiJSON._links.self.href
```

Now I try to link the Task:

This works fine:

```
   $url1="https://dev.azure.com/myOrgName/_apis/projects/myProjectName?api-version=6.0"
   $response1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url1 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get 
   $projectid = $response1.id
```

This works fine:

```
   $url2=-join("https://dev.azure.com/myOrgName/myProjectName/_apis/git/repositories/","myRepoName","?api-version=4.1")
   $response2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url2 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get 
   $repoid = $response2.id
```

Now I prepare the update:

```
   $urlBranch = "vstfs:///Git/Ref/$projectid/$repoid/GB$branchFullName" 
   $body = "[{
       `"op`": `"add`",
       `"path`": `"/relations/-`",
       `"value`": {
         `"rel`": `"ArtifactLink`",
         `"url`": `"$urlBranch`",
         `"attributes`": {
           `"name`": `"Branch`", `"comment`": `"WorkItem now linked to Branch`"
         }
       }
     }]"
```

This does not give an error:

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$($TaskURL)?api-version=5.1" -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $($token)"} -Method Patch -Body $body -ContentType application/json-patch+json
```

The new link is even in the relations table:

```
PS C:\> $response.relations
rel                                url                                                                                                                                             attributes
---                                ---                                                                                                                                             ----------
System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse https://dev.azure.com/myOrgName/814f3adb-0000-0000-0000-86f800358def/_apis/wit/workItems/22863                                                   @{isLocked=False; name=Parent}
ArtifactLink                       vstfs:///Git/Ref/bf55baa4-0000-0000-0000-1e34326fb51c/481ec5d3-0000-0000-0000-6a4db6e82610/GBfeature/0024468-New_program_to_do_something @{authorizedDate=2/14/2024 5:01:41 AM; id=2…
```

But in the AzDO web site I see this information on the Task's page, in the Development/Branch area (on the right side of the screen):
(!) Branch link could not be read
where '(!)' is a red icon with a exclamation dot.

Note: GUIDs have been obfuscated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the same issue when setting the value of "**`url`**" to be "**`vstfs:///Git/Ref/{project}/{repository}/GB{branch}`**".

After changing it to be "**`vstfs:///Git/Ref/{project}%2F{repository}%2FGB{branch}`**", the issue gets fixed.

After the prefix "**`vstfs:///Git/Ref/`**", you need to replace all the forward slash (**`/`**) with the "**`%2F`**". If the branch name contains the forward slash, you also need to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the suggestion that `ArtifactLink` should include `%2f` instead of `/`? Examples:

[image]

[image]